# How to split the custom logs and add custom field name in each values on logstash

Tags: arrays, filter, split, logstash

I want to split the custom logs

"2016-05-11 02:38:00.617,userTestId,Key-string-test113321,UID-123,10079,0,30096,128,3"

that log means

Timestamp, String userId, String setlkey, String uniqueId, long providerId, String itemCode1, String itemCode2, String itemCode3, String serviceType

I try to made a filter using ruby

```
filter {
        ruby{
        code => "
        fieldArray = event['message'].split(',')
        for field in fieldArray
                result = field
                event[field[0]] = result
end
"
}
}
```

but I don't have idea how to split the logs with adding field names each custom values as belows.

```
Timestamp : 2016-05-11 02:38:00.617
userId : userTestId
setlkey : Key-string-test113321
uniqueId : UID-123
providerId : 10079
itemCode1 : 0
itemCode2 : 30096
itemCode3 : 128
serviceType : 3
```

How can I do?

Thanks regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the grok filter instead. The grok filter parse the line with a regex and you can associate each group to a field.
It is possible to parse your log with this pattern :

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [
           "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{USERNAME:userId},%{USERNAME:setlkey},%{USERNAME:uniqueId},%{NUMBER:providerId},%{NUMBER:itemCode1},%{NUMBER:itemCode2},%{NUMBER:itemCode3},%{NUMBER:serviceType}"
        ]
    }
}
```

This will create the fields you wish to have.
Reference: [grok patterns on github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)
To test : [Grok constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result)

---

Another solution :
You can use the csv filter, which is even more closer to your needs (but I went with grok filter first since I have more experience with it): [Csv filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html)

> The CSV filter takes an event field containing CSV data, parses it, and stores it as individual fields (**can optionally specify the names**). This filter can also parse data with any separator, not just commas.

I have never used it, but it should look like this :

```
csv {
   columns => [ "Timestamp", "userId", "setlkey", "uniqueId", "providerId", "itemCode1", "itemCode2 "itemCode3", "serviceType"  ]
}
```

By default, the filter is on the message field, with the `","` separator, so there no need to configure them.

I think that the csv filter solution is better.

Comment: Also it might be possible to do it with the ruby filter, but I have no experience the ruby filter and ruby itself, so I can't say

Comment: Dear. Baudsp. It's really helpul for me. Thank you very much~!